# Downloading custom image sizes with iOS

Tags: ios, image, asynchronous, uiimageview, android-glide

I am hitting a server that has already thumbnailed images.  To get a thumbnail of an image you just set a size attribute in the URL for the image resource.

I am using bumptech/glide in an Android project and it works perfectly.  IE for glide you implement a method that is passed the width and height of the view (calculated by glide) and you can use that to determine how to make the request for an image that size (or close) to the server, ie:

```
public class MyUrlLoader extends BaseGlideUrlLoader<MyDataModel> {
    @Override
    protected String getUrl(MyDataModel model, int width, int height) {
        // Construct the url for the correct size here.
        return model.buildUrl(width, height);
    }
}
```

Is there something like this for iOS?  I am using FastImageCache from some of the caching, but I don't think it has this type of support.

Worst I guess would be to just roll my own (maybe a category) that calculates what size image to request based on the image view size.  If I do that its probably pretty easy to grab the height and width or the imageview, but do I need to factor in the size/scale of the device (1x, 2x or 3x)?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to build the appropriate URL. But it's not clear from your question what the URL looks like, but it's just one line of code, using string interpolation for Swift or `stringWithFormat` in Objective-C.

And, yes, you do want to factor in the scale when building the appropriate URL for the image view of a particular size (e.g. a 44 x 44 point image view on device with scale of 3 should be requesting an image that is 132 x 132 pixels).

Regarding requesting the image and caching it, you can write your own, as it's trivial. When you request images via `NSURLSession`, it seamlessly caches it behind the scenes with `NSURLCache` (with a few caveats). If you need something a little more advanced (e.g. you're updating images in table view or collection view and want to perform lazy loading), you might consider one of the many `UIImageView` extensions for asynchronous fetching of images (e.g. in Objective-C, I'd consider AFNetworking's UIKit categories, or maybe use SDWebImage; in Swift, I'd consider AlamofireImage, DFImageManager, or Kingfisher).

Comment: With respect to downloading @2x and @3x images from an API, one can only download an image of @1x scale. So an image scaled on the backend before the API call may be transmitted at the correct size in pixels, but UIKit interprets that image's `size` to be in points @1x, not in pixels. What's the best way to set the image scale without programmatically upscaling or downscaling the image?

Comment: If you download a JPEG/PNG representation, `data`, that is an image at, say, 300x300 px, you can then create the `UIImage` with `UIImage(data: data, scale: 3)` and the resulting image is 100x100 with a scale of 3.